# Deleting specific columns of text in Emacs/XEmacs using the keyboard

Tags: text, emacs, gnu, xemacs

Is it possible to delete specific columns of text (i.e., particular column numbers) in Emacs/XEmacs using only the keyboard?  I know that it is possible to select a rectangle of text using the mouse (or the arrow keys), but for a 1 million line text file, this can be quite time consuming.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can delete a rectangle with `delete-rectangle` (<kbd>C-x r d</kbd>) or `kill-rectangle` (<kbd>C-x r k</kbd>).  Either one will kill the rectangle with corners defined by the point and the mark.  `kill-rectangle` will also save it for yanking with `yank-rectangle`.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make a selection rectangle quickly (without using the mouse), for a one million line text file?  I have tried holding down shift while holding Page Up or Page Down to quickly scroll through and select text, but this is still relatively slow.

Comment: I suggest writing a quick SED script for jobs that large.

Comment: If you want to delete the column for every line, first set the mark at the beginning of the column on the first line, then hit `end-of-buffer` (`M->`), move to the end of the column on the last line, and run `delete-rectangle`.

Comment: sed might indeed be a better choice, or a small elisp program run with `emacs --batch --script`.

Comment: Thanks. Even when I hold shift, `M->` brings me to the end of the buffer but does not select--the selection is dropped, at least in XEmacs on Windows.  I guess I will need to write a script, but I have never done this.

Comment: You don't need to hold shift.  Start by setting the mark with `C-space`, then `M->`.  The region should now be active.  Even though it will be highlighted as lines, rectangle commands will still operate on a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `sed` or `awk` on your system, you can conveniently use `C-u M-|`.

From the documentation:

> M-| runs the command shell-command-on-region [...]
>
> Execute string COMMAND in inferior shell with region as input.
>   Normally display output (if any) in temp buffer `*Shell Command Output*';
>   Prefix arg means replace the region with it.  Return the exit code of
>   COMMAND. [...]

Note the bit about the prefix arg (`C-u`).

Tip: `C-x h` will set the region to your whole buffer.